# PHP If switch for a multidimensional array with an Unknown

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, arrayiterator

Just curious if there's a way to do this in a `If` switch

```
$account = array (
'{unkown value}' => 
    array (
      'accountID' => '4430290',
      'accountStatus' => '1',
      'parentAccountID' => '',
      'offerID' => '746',
      'billingModel' => '2.0',
    ),
);


if(array_pop($account)['billingModel'] == 'SomeValue') {
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm currently doing this, but thought there might be a better way

```
        $model = array_pop($accountInfo);
        if ($model['billingModel'] == 'someValue') return false;
```

Comment: Newer versions of php allow you to chain expressions like that.

Comment: I believe it was introduced in 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of php allow you to chain expressions like that. Examples:

php 5.3: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4zgSxW

php 5.4: http://codepad.viper-7.com/oGtKqc

Both use the same code:

```
<?php
$array = array(range(1,5), range(6,10), range(11, 15));

if(array_shift($array)[0] == 1){
    echo "hello";   
}
```

5.3 shows a parse error. 5.4 shows the expected output.

Comment: Unfortunately this needs to be 5.3 compliant, +1 for a neat 5.4 trick though.

Comment: @ehime thats my point, it doesn't work in 5.3 as you requested. Only in >= 5.4. In 5.3 you would have to do it like you are suggesting, two lines, or in a loop. foreach or while work well with unknown keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do something if subarray element is with some value , then you must actually look into array_search()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php